# spacedlowsmallcaps undefined in moderncv

Tags: moderncv, small-caps, cv

I'd like to apply `\spacedlowsmallcaps` to my CV's (moderncv) section headings, yet I keep getting an error message telling me the control sequence was undefined. `\spacedallcaps` doesn't work either, however `\scshape` does.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.27\textwidth}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}    
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{Lorem Ipsum}{Dolor Sit, Amet}
\mobile{(000) 111 1111}
\phone{(000) 111 1112}
\fax{(000) 111 1113}
\email{john@doe.com}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Persönliche Angaben}} %no error when using \scshape

\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What makes you think it's a standard command? It's defined by `classicthesis.sty`, as far as I know. But it's of course incompatible with `moderncv.cls`.

Comment: And there is no way of implementing the command?

Comment: Did you try `\lsstyle` from microtype, coupled with `\scshape`  (if I understand well what `\spacedlowsmallcaps` does)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of `\spacedlowsmallcaps` in `classicthesis.sty`, provided `microtype` is loaded, is

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedlowsmallcaps}[1]{%
  \textls[80]{\scshape\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}%
}
```

Remember to add

```
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{textcase}
```

to your preamble.

However, for `moderncv` you have to follow a different strategy:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{microtype,textcase}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.27\textwidth}

\renewcommand{\sectionfont}{\Large\normalfont\scshape}
\renewcommand{\sectionstyle}[1]{%
  \sectionfont\textcolor{color1}{\textls[80]{\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}%
}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}    
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{Lorem Ipsum}{Dolor Sit, Amet}
\mobile{(000) 111 1111}
\phone{(000) 111 1112}
\fax{(000) 111 1113}
\email{john@doe.com}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Persönliche Angaben} %no error when using \scshape

Other text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That does almost exactly what i wanted. Yet it doesn't work when included in a `\section` command.

Comment: @Pajogeri I added the correct strategy for `moderncv`